# Session Bean doesn't work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a `SessionBean` and want to load DATA from an InfoHolder Class called `Benutzer`. But it doesn't work.

```
 /*
 * SessionBean1.java
 *
 * Created on 21.06.2009, 16:03:41
 */

package egispartnerprofile;

import com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractSessionBean;
import group52.infoholders.Benutzer;
import javax.faces.FacesException;

/**
 * <p>Session scope data bean for your application.  Create properties
 *  here to represent cached data that should be made available across
 *  multiple HTTP requests for an individual user.</p>
 *
 * <p>An instance of this class will be created for you automatically,
 * the first time your application evaluates a value binding expression
 * or method binding expression that references a managed bean using
 * this class.</p>
 *
 * @author reBourne
 */
public class SessionBean1 extends AbstractSessionBean {


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Managed Component Definition">

    /**
     * <p>Automatically managed component initialization.  <strong>WARNING:</strong>
     * This method is automatically generated, so any user-specified code inserted
     * here is subject to being replaced.</p>
     */
    private void _init() throws Exception {
    }
    // </editor-fold>
private String user;
private Benutzer bntzr ;
    /**
     * <p>Construct a new session data bean instance.</p>
     */
    public SessionBean1() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>This method is called when this bean is initially added to
     * session scope.  Typically, this occurs as a result of evaluating
     * a value binding or method binding expression, which utilizes the
     * managed bean facility to instantiate this bean and store it into
     * session scope.</p>
     * 
     * <p>You may customize this method to initialize and cache data values
     * or resources that are required for the lifetime of a particular
     * user session.</p>
     */

    public SessionBean1(Benutzer benutzer) {
        this.bntzr = benutzer;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Perform initializations inherited from our superclass
        super.init();
        // Perform application initialization that must complete
        // *before* managed components are initialized
        // TODO - add your own initialiation code here

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Managed Component Initialization">
        // Initialize automatically managed components
        // *Note* - this logic should NOT be modified
        try {
            _init();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("SessionBean1 Initialization Failure", e);
            throw e instanceof FacesException ? (FacesException) e: new FacesException(e);
        }

        // </editor-fold>
        // Perform application initialization that must complete
        // *after* managed components are initialized
        // TODO - add your own initialization code here
    }

    /**
     * <p>This method is called when the session containing it is about to be
     * passivated.  Typically, this occurs in a distributed servlet container
     * when the session is about to be transferred to a different
     * container instance, after which the <code>activate()</code> method
     * will be called to indicate that the transfer is complete.</p>
     * 
     * <p>You may customize this method to release references to session data
     * or resources that can not be serialized with the session itself.</p>
     */
    @Override
    public void passivate() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>This method is called when the session containing it was
     * reactivated.</p>
     * 
     * <p>You may customize this method to reacquire references to session
     * data or resources that could not be serialized with the
     * session itself.</p>
     */
    @Override
    public void activate() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>This method is called when this bean is removed from
     * session scope.  Typically, this occurs as a result of
     * the session timing out or being terminated by the application.</p>
     * 
     * <p>You may customize this method to clean up resources allocated
     * during the execution of the <code>init()</code> method, or
     * at any later time during the lifetime of the application.</p>
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>Return a reference to the scoped data bean.</p>
     *
     * @return reference to the scoped data bean
     */
    protected ApplicationBean1 getApplicationBean1() {
        return (ApplicationBean1) getBean("ApplicationBean1");
    }

    public // </editor-fold>
    String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    }
```

This does work .

But when i am using bntzr... then nothing works anymore :/
Is there any nontrivial Example ?

Comment: A great example for how mixing languages in code confuses readers. Oh, and Achtung is kind of inappropriate to ask a question, in German and even more in English.

Comment: What do you mean by mixing languages ? sry.. for the Achtung :/

Comment: Benutzer undoubtly. While I know what you mean, being flemish, it is difficult to put everything into context for English readers. Imagine reading sourcecode where the classes all have, say, italian names.

Comment: -- even though that is the only instance I see looking at your code

Comment: `Benutzer` is Serializable, with a parameterless default constructor?

Comment: Please show the class `group52.infoholders.Benutzer`. Are there getter and setter functions, like: public Benutzer getBenutzer() { return bntzr; } public void setBenutzer(Benutzer bntzr ) { this.bntzr = bntzr; }

Answer (score 0):

Use this : group52.infoholders.Benutzer.

Are there getter and setter functions, like: public Benutzer getBenutzer() { return bntzr; } public void setBenutzer(Benutzer bntzr ) { this.bntzr = bntzr; }